# Evaluate an Improper Integral by Reversing the Order of Integration.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble solving this question. This is a problem for a multivariable calculus course (Calculus "3")

**Reversing the Order of Integration.** Evaluate (showing all the steps) the improper integral

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2} - e^{-x^2/4}} x\ dx$$

So far, I have done the following:

1. Rewrote the integral as

$$\int_{0}^\infty \int_{\frac{-x^{2}}4}^ {-x^2} \frac{e^{y}}x\ dy\ dx$$

2. Reverse the order of inegration:

$$\int_{0}^{-\infty} \int_{(-y)^{1/2}}^ {2(-y)^{1/2}} \frac{e^{y}}x\ dx\ dy$$

This gets really messy and I can't figure it out. Am I on the right path? Can someone help me with some guidance? Can't meet with my professor for at least a couple days. Much appreciated!

Comment: It appears that you have correctly reversed the integrals. You should get a negative number as your answer. And it is not at all messy. The $e^y$ is a constant and can be written in front of the inside integral.

Comment: Thank you much John. I realized I made a small mistake at the very end where I was evaluating the limits of integration on the outside integral.

Comment: You're welcome.